# submitting form to ajax function, but it's reloading the page as well

Tags: jquery

my question is probably really simple, but i'll ask anyways.

So I have a submit button in my form that has an onclick="ajax()" and at the same time the action of the form is action=""

I notice at the execution of my form the page it is sill redirecting to whatever is in my action code.

What should I be doing when doing ajax form submissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery do it jQuery's way (do not call the function in the `onclick`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonId").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do submit here
    });
});
```

Or use [malsup's AJAX form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Answer (score 5):

use `return false;`

```
onclick="ajax();return false;"
```

Answer (score 4):

Submit buttons submit your form. Use a regular button. `input type="button"`

Comment: This works, and I added 1, but Adeel has a better answer because it deprecates if they don't have javascript turned on.  (Not that this is that big of a concern these days, but it does allow for some odd browsers to access sites.)

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is `preventDefault` form you ajax function so that the submit doesnt get triggered

so it would look like this:

```
onclick="ajax(event)"

function ajax(e){
  ...
  e.preventDefault();
}
```